# Since $\Bbb{Z}/(p)$ is a ring and $(\Bbb{Z}/p)^{\times} \simeq \Bbb{Z}/(p-1)$ which is also a ring, how do they relate?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, integers

Let $p$ be an odd prime, then according to: [wikipedia article,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n#Cyclic_case) we have that $(\Bbb{Z}/(p))^{\times} \simeq (\Bbb{Z}/(p-1))^+$.  Then how does multiplication in the *ring* on the right affect the first ring, and why don't we call the first ring $(\Bbb{Z}/(p), +, \times, *)$, where $*$ is the second multiplication operation?

---

$\cdot$ on $\Bbb{Z}/(p)$ is a binary map $\mu : \Bbb{Z}/(p) \times \Bbb{Z}/(p) \to \Bbb{Z}/(p)$ written $\mu(x,y) = x\cdot y$.  But multiplication $*$ acts distributively as $z * (x \cdot y) = z * x \cdot z * y = x\cdot x \cdot x (z \text{ times}) \cdot y \cdot y \cdot y (z \text{ times}) = (x\cdot y)^z$ since we're in commutative settings.

Comment: $2$ is a generator of $\mathbb{Z}/(5)^\times$ so $a \mapsto 2^a$ is a group isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/(4) \to \mathbb{Z}/(5)^\times$ and hence a ring isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/(4) \to \mathbb{Z}/(5)^\times$, where the addition and multiplication on the latter are $2^n \oplus 2^m = 2^{n+m}, 2^n \otimes 2^m = 2^{nm}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this idea is that $*$ depends on the precise isomorphism used between the $(\mathbb{Z}/(p))^\times$ and $(\mathbb{Z}/(p-1))^+$.  For example, in the latter ring, $0$ and $1$ both square to themselves.  The preimage of $0$ is $1$, but the preimage of $1$ is any (non-1) element of $(\mathbb{Z}/(p))^\times$.

---

More explanation, per request.  One way to establish the isomorphism $\phi$ between $\mathbb{Z}_7^\times$ and $\mathbb{Z}_6^+$ is to send $2$ to $1$.  Now, in the latter ring, $1\times 1=1$; hence, with this new operation, $2*2=2$.  In the first ring, $4=2\times 2$, hence $\phi(4)=\phi(2)+\phi(2)=1+1=2$.  Hence, $4*4=\phi^{-1}(2\times 2)=\phi^{-1}(4)=\phi^{-1}(1+1+1+1)=2\times 2\times 2\times 2=16=2$.

But, a different way to establish the isomorphism is to send $4$ to $1$.  Now, again $1\times 1=1$ in the latter ring, so $4*4=4$.

---

In short, what you need is actually $(\mathbb{Z}/(p),+,\times,\phi,*)$, where $*$ depends on $\phi$.  This makes $*$ not particularly natural.  If you were to find interesting properties of $*$, people might care, but otherwise it's just another potential binary operation.

Comment: I'm not sure about this.  Could you explain more?

Comment: Isn't the fact that this happens on all fields of prime order significant? Do we always have an exponentiation operation that is a closed binary operator on all of $\Bbb{Z}/n$?